# Construct an arithmetic code for the source and calculate its length

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, entropy

Construct an arithmetic code for the following source:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
s_k&1&2&3&4\\
p_k&0.45&0.1&0.1&0.35\end{array}$$
I am confused, almost all examples I see online have a 'message' in their question/example. So it will give a source of letters, and then say "encode the message 'eaii', whereas this just says 'construct a code'. It doesn't say 'encode the message 1123' for example.

If you can give me any pointers it would help, I am not asking for a solution if it is very long

Comment: Could you point us to online examples of that first type that you encountered before?

Comment: Yes. in this video the example is 'went.' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yYgRAHtDLk

Comment: and in this lecture on page 4 the example is 'vowellish'. They both encode the examples using arithmetic coding

Comment: But how does the receiver decode? In a Huffman code you sent the (coded version of the) tree, what is the equivalent here?

Comment: i dont really know what you mean. i found the [solution](https://gyazo.com/1ea53b43899e5ac99ae2cac5a85a99a5) to the question and it is a table with the pmf, then the pmf sorted into a range, then certain other parameters and it arrives at a binary code for each symbol 1,2,3,4. There is a process like that in my lecture notes but it is slightly different and i do not see anything online with that 'table' of parameters in it so i was confused. thank you for your help

Comment: I agree, it looks weird to me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the other type of problem you also first had to construct a code for the input symbols, and then show that you understood the definition of that just constructed code by encoding an example message.

This problem is easier, because you don't have to do the second thing.

Comment: Sorry for not replying and giving the example sooner. I am not sure I am using the right example, in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yYgRAHtDLk) the girl uses her probability mass function of letters [e n t w .] to encode the message 'went.' that is the first thing she does. then she gets a 'range' and a 'tag' and uses this to decode.. also in this [example](http://www.ws.binghamton.edu/fowler/fowler%20personal%20page/EE523_files/Ch_04%20Arithmetic%20Coding%20(PPT).pdf|) the same 'arithmetic coding' happens. So they did 'the second thing' as the first? @henno